# Expecting some solution for implemeting listview with checkboxes .....

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting an issue while checking the dynamically generated checkbox through list view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738527/getting-an-issue-while-checking-the-dynamically-generated-checkbox-through-list)

I want to implement a listview with textview and checkbox per row of a list. I am doing that using LayoutInflator. By this I am getting whatever I want in a list. But whenever I scroll the list, functions from my listviewadapter class calls again and again and recycles the list every time.

Because of this my checkbox state is not maintaining and also if I checked first item of list it will also checks the second last item of a list itself. I tried to find out by debugging my code. I came to know that once my all items from arraylist got its view this getView() function picks some random position and replace the view on that position.

I am totally confused ........ has anybody implemented such kind of listview please tell me the solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738527/getting-an-issue-while-checking-the-dynamically-generated-checkbox-through-list/7739006#7739006), Knickedi has nicely explained the working of ListView and also the problem why the checkbox is behaving in a weird manner.

Answer (score 0):

use alert dialog box...

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);                 

builder.setTitle(<title>);                  
builder.setMultiChoiceItems(<List_View_Item_Array>, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {                 

    }
});

AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```